# Building e-commerce with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am building an e-commerce website and have choosen [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) to setup basic store. I am confused on how to add my products. My products are different from the default Product model that spree provides. I am aware I can use decorators to add methods, associations and attributes to the Spree models. Can I also remove attributes from Spree models? If my product is different from how the Spree has defined it's default, should I customize their product model or should I think of creating new model and add associations that I will need for features like shopping cart? Can I rename Spree models? Say I want to change Spree Product model to a different name which is more suitable to my product, can I do it? I would appreciate links to good blogs about building e-commerce site using Spree.

Comment: You'd likely get more help if you have done something, get some error messages then we can get the ball rolling. ;) Spree is also fully customizable

Comment: I have started working on it :-). I am trying to understand how should I go with building my store. I can either use the current models which would speed up development though I just need to know if I can also remove features from models as I can add them.